# Keeping dirs in order with GNU Parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel

I need to copy a large amount of files into their own directories. The issue I am having is keeping them in order when I copy them with GNU parallel. For example, file_1.output gets placed in dir_19.

Here is what I have so far that is working, besides the order of files.

```
ls *.output > copy.list
parallel "mkdir cele_{}" ::: {1..10000}
parallel -k --link "cp {} cele_{}" :::: copy.list ::: {1..10000}
```

Is there a way to do this without sacrificing parallel?

(Inspired by https://rbt.asia/g/thread/64890073/#64890111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--rpl` to define your own replacement string and then use that both for `mkdir` and `cp`.

```
ls *.output |  parallel --rpl '{dir} s/\.output$/_dir/' 'mkdir {dir} && cp {} {dir}'
```